# How can I get a node from an XML document based on its attribute value and into an XElement object?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, xelement

I need to inject some XML into a pre-existing XML file under a certain node.  Here is the code I have to create my XML:

```
//Define the nodes
XElement dataItemNode = new XElement("DataItem");
XElement setterNodeDisplayName = new XElement("Setter");
XElement setterNodeOU = new XElement("Setter");

//Create the tree with the nodes
dataItemNode.Add(setterNodeDisplayName);
dataItemNode.Add(setterNodeOU);

//Define the attributes
XAttribute nameAttrib = new XAttribute("Name", "OrganizationalUnits");
XAttribute displayNameAttrib = new XAttribute("Property", "DisplayName");
XAttribute ouAttrib = new XAttribute("Property", "OU");

//Attach the attributes to the nodes
setterNodeDisplayName.Add(displayNameAttrib);
setterNodeOU.Add(ouAttrib);

//Set the values for each node
setterNodeDisplayName.SetValue("TESTING DISPLAY NAME");
setterNodeOU.SetValue("OU=funky-butt,OU=super,OU=duper,OU=TMI,DC=rompa-room,DC=pbs,DC=com");
```

Here is the code I have so far to load up the XML document and try to get the node that I need to insert my XML under:

```
//Load up the UDI Wizard XML file
XDocument udiXML = XDocument.Load("UDIWizard_Config.xml");

//Get the node that I need to append to and then append my XML to it
XElement ouNode = THIS IS WHAT I DONT KNOW HOW TO DO
ouNode.Add(dataItemNode);
```

Here is the XML from the existing document I am trying to work with:

```
<Data Name="OrganizationalUnits">
        <DataItem>
          <Setter Property="DisplayName">TESTING DISPLAY NAME</Setter>
          <Setter Property="OU">OU=funky-butt,OU=super,OU=duper,OU=TMI,DC=rompa-room,DC=pbs,DC=com</Setter>
        </DataItem>
```

I have multiple nodes that with the name of "Data", but I need to get the node that is , and I don't know how.  Just learning how to use XML with C#.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get the first `Data` node with `Name` attribute matching *OrganizationalUnits*:

```
var ouNode = udiXML
    .Descendants("Data")
    .Where(n => n.Attribute("Name") != null)
    .Where(n => n.Attribute("Name").Value == "OrganizationalUnits")
    .First();
```

If your document might contain `Data` nodes without `Name` attribute, extra check for null might be necessary.

Note that you can achieve the same result with XPath (this will select root `Data` node, you can get `DataItem` node using [`Element`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element.aspx) method):

```
var ouNode = udiXML.XPathSelectElement("//Data[@Name = 'OrganizationalUnits']");
```

Comment: It actually went a little further than that and returned the <DataItem> that was underneath the <Data Name="OrganizationalUnits">.

Comment: The second example using Xpath got me what I wanted.  Thanks so much!